# Which is the kernel build directory (4.4.0-17134-Microsoft build)?

Tags: microsoft

How can I fix the following issue (4.4.0-17134-Microsoft build)?

```
checking for Linux kernel build in /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/build... not found
checking for Linux kernel build in /usr/src/linux-4.4.0-17134-Microsoft-obj... not found
checking for Linux kernel build in /usr/src/linux-4.4.0-17134-Microsoft... not found
checking for Linux kernel build in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-17134-Microsoft... not found
checking for Linux kernel build in /usr/src/kernels/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft... not found
**configure: error: Could not find a directory containing a Linux kernel 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft build.  Perhaps try --with-linux=FULL_PATH_TO_KERNEL_BUILD**
```